# Android - A variable might not have been initialized

Tags: android

Trying to create a BMI Calculator I already declared a variable for weight and height, but still I'm getting an error of "variable "weight" might not have been initialized.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText eheight, eweight;
private Button computeb;
private TextView output, category;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    eheight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eheight);
    eweight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eweight);
    output = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
    category = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.category);
    computeb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.computeb);

    computeb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            float weight, height, BMI;

            if (checkInputLength())
                return;
            weight = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
            height = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
            computeBMI(weight, height);

            BMI = weight / (height * height);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: what do you expect `weight.getText()` will do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
weight = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
height = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
```

to

```
weight = Float.parseFloat(eweight.getText().toString());
height = Float.parseFloat(eheight.getText().toString());
```

**weight and height are just float variables**.If you want to parse data from `edittext` then you have to get the data from the edittexts and store them in the corresponding variables.

Answer (score 1):

weight.getText()? weight is a float type value which is not initialized here. I think you want to use eweight. And the same with height.

```
            weight = Float.parseFloat(eweight.getText().toString());
            height = Float.parseFloat(eheight.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

just set it 0.

```
float weight = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
weight = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
```

to:

```
weight = Float.parseFloat(eweight.getText().toString());
```